# Process return doesn't support French characters vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding

I'm trying to start a process in VB.NET with this :

```
    MyProcess = New Process
    With MyProcess.StartInfo
        .FileName = "CMD.EXE"
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
    End With
    MyProcess.Start()
    MyProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()
    MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

But answer are bad because the french caracters are not supported :

```
Private Sub MyProcess_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles MyProcess.OutputDataReceived
    Debug.Print("Process Return=" & e.Data)
    processOutput = processOutput + e.Data + vbCrLf
End Sub
```

It returm something like :

Process Return=Vous ˆtes d‚j… connect‚ sur VPN.
Process Return=La commande a ‚t‚ ex‚cut‚e.

Does anyone had an idea to how got all french character ?
Thank YOU

Comment: You can never ignore the code page when you run a console app.  You didn't fill in your SO profile so we don't know where you are from and what code page you might be using.  If the program was written by a French programmer then he'd expect code page 437.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way :
I execute this command prior : "chcp 1252"
And now it's work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to define another Encoding before starting the process ?

```
Imports System.Text

    MyProcess = New Process
    With MyProcess.StartInfo
        .FileName = "CMD.EXE"
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True

        .StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;  ' <- here
        .StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; ' <-
        ' or any other encoding.
    End With
    MyProcess.Start()
    MyProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()
    MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

But there is no guarantee this could work. A test on the process is required to have a look..